# Запись данных в datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms

Здравствуйте. Есть на форме dataGridView. Прицепил к нему databindingsource и в нём таблица из моей бд. Но в таблице внешний ключ на клиента, а мне нужно вместо айдишинка туда запихать ФИО, поэтому я создал через edit column ещё 1 столбец отвязанный от данных и туда вручную запихиваю ФИО, вроде как значение запихалось, но не отображается, что нужно ещё сделать? Может как то данные забиндить? ВОт как я это делаю.

```
Clients client = db.Clients.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == ClientId);
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = (client.Surname + " " + client.Name + " " + client.Patronymic);
```

Подскажите пожалуйста что я делаю не так.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, в классе Clients переопредели метод ToString()

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return Surname + " " + Name + " " + Patronymic;
}
```

А к дгв подвяжи например так

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = db.ТвояТаблица.Local.ToBindingList();
```

Но мне кажется это далеко не самый лучший вариант)